# how to divide if-else statements into sub-methods in Python?

Tags: python, function

I had this code part initially:

```
def ObjectInteractionWithRightHand():
    for item in itemList:
        if (item.isCollidingOnCoords(rightHandCoords) and
                player.getItemInRightHand() is None):
            if (player.isGrasped(rightHand.z, rightElbow.z)):
                player.setItemInRightHand(item)
        elif player.getItemInRightHand() is not None and \
                player.isReleased(rightHandCoords[1], rightWristCoords[1]):
            player.setItemInRightHand(None)
```

I tried to seperate if else statements into two sub methods to make it smaller:

```
def ObjectInteractionWithRightHand():
    for item in itemList:
        graspObjectWithRightHand(item)
        releaseObjectFromRightHand()

def graspObjectWithRightHand(item):
    if (item.isCollidingOnCoords(rightHandCoords) and
            player.getItemInRightHand() is None):
        if (player.isGrasped(rightHand.z, rightElbow.z)):
            player.setItemInRightHand(item)
def releaseObjectFromRightHand():
    if player.getItemInRightHand() is not None and \
            player.isReleased(rightHandCoords[1], rightWristCoords[1]):
        player.setItemInRightHand(None)
```

My question is, is this code "clean" enough? What I mean is that I am iterating an "item" list and calling two methods: "graspObjectWithRightHand(item)" and "releaseObjectFromRightHand()", but there is no indicator when will be one of these methods executed. How can I make this cleaner?

Comment: My opinion:   The original code is preferable.   The amount of code in the original is not enough to warrant refactoring, and the particular refactoring you propose tends to confuse the intent of the conditionals.

Comment: Your second snippet is not equivalent to the first. The first snippet is: `if/elif`, whereas the second is: `if/if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplification you don't have to explicitly compare to `None`, so `if x is not None` will become `if x`. (and `if x is None` becomes `if not x`)

Applying this:

```
def ObjectInteractionWithRightHand():
    for item in itemList:
        if (item.isCollidingOnCoords(rightHandCoords) and
                not player.getItemInRightHand()):
            if (player.isGrasped(rightHand.z, rightElbow.z)):
                player.setItemInRightHand(item)
        elif player.getItemInRightHand() and \
                player.isReleased(rightHandCoords[1], rightWristCoords[1]):
            player.setItemInRightHand(None)
```

Next, the order of the conditionals could be changed to make it more readable. Also, lets include comments for clarity!

```
def ObjectInteractionWithRightHand():
    for item in itemList:
        # if RightHand is free, try to pick the item up
        if not player.getItemInRightHand():
            if item.isCollidingOnCoords(rightHandCoords)) and \
                player.isGrasped(rightHand.z, rightElbow.z):
                player.setItemInRightHand(item)
        # if RightHand is not free and we're releasing an item.
        elif player.isReleased(rightHandCoords[1], rightWristCoords[1]):
                player.setItemInRightHand(None)
```

This function does not have enough lines of code to justify separating responsibilities into different functions. If you find yourself reusing this evaluation in other functions as well, then it may be worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two first if statements into one

```
def ObjectInteractionWithRightHand():
    for item in itemList:
        if (item.isCollidingOnCoords(rightHandCoords) and
            player.getItemInRightHand() is None and 
            player.isGrasped(rightHand.z, rightElbow.z)):
                player.setItemInRightHand(item)
        elif player.getItemInRightHand() is not None and
             player.isReleased(rightHandCoords[1], rightWristCoords[1]):
                 player.setItemInRightHand(None)
```

And then remove the condition from whitin the if statement to its own function. The elif statement can be replaced by `else`:

```
def ObjectInteractionWithRightHand():
    for item in itemList:
        if (RightHandIsReady(item, player)):
            player.setItemInRightHand(item)
        else:
            player.setItemInRightHand(None)

def RightHandIsReady(item, player):
    return  item.isCollidingOnCoords(rightHandCoords) and \
            player.getItemInRightHand() is None and \
            player.isGrasped(rightHand.z, rightElbow.z)
```

Comment: By combining the first two `if` statements into one, you're changing the code's functionality: Originally the `elif` would be evaluated if the first `if` is false, but now it's evaluated if the combined `if` is false.

Comment: Additionally, your final version removed the condition in the `elif` statement when you turned it into `else`.